# How to prompt the user to input a file into a function along with a min and max?

Tags: python, string, function, loops

I need to make it so rather than this function relying on an parameters from the user when they call the function, it instead gets called, and then prompts the user to enter a FILE name for it to read (ex. they enter "dna.txt"), and then prompts them to enter a mink and a maxk and then it runs through the code of going through this file and finding the most common substring within the given mink and maxk. This is my current code:

```
def mostCommonSubstring(dna, mink, maxk):
    count = 0
    check = 0
    answer = ""
    k = mink
    while k <= maxk:
        for i in range(len(dna)-k+1):
            sub = dna[i:i+k]
            count = 0
            for i in range(len(dna)-k+1):
                if dna[i:i+k] == sub:
                    count = count + 1
            if count >= check:
                answer = sub
                check = count
        k=k+1
    print(answer)
    print(check)
```

I am under the impression that is needs to look something like this (but this code doesn't work?):

```
def mostCommonSubstring():
    dnaFile = input("Enter file: ")
    dna = open(dnaFile, "r")
    mink = input("Enter a min: ")
    maxk = input("Enter a max: ")
    count = 0
    check = 0
    answer = ""
    k = mink
    while k <= maxk:
        for i in range(len(dna)-k+1):
            sub = dna[i:i+k]
            count = 0
            for i in range(len(dna)-k+1):
                if dna[i:i+k] == sub:
                    count = count + 1
            if count >= check:
                answer = sub
                check = count
        k=k+1
    print(answer)
    print(check)
```

(The DNA file is a large file that contains many many a, g, t, and c, sequences. I wanted to be able to have the user input this file along with a min and max and then have the program find the longest common string.)

Comment: You can't treat a file as if it's a list that you can access randomly with `dna[i:i+k]`. You need to read the file contents into a string.

Comment: Or mmap it (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/mmap.html#module-mmap).

Answer (score 0):

I know I have a high chance of being wrong here but I'll try to help anyway.
As a beginner I examined your code, and I think you could more use something like this:

```
with open(dna, 'r') as dnaFile:
    # Do whatever you want here...
```

this will let you to run the file as a string.
IF I am not wrong, your problem was that you indeed opened the file, but you have not actually read it into a string. Thus you tried to access a file as if its contents we're already pressed into a string.

**EDIT**:
You could also do something like:

```
dna = open(dnaFile, 'r')  # This is from your code.
dnaString = dna.read()
```

This way you also would read the file's content into a string and continue to run on your code.

Good luck and best regards!